# how to update database from query

Tags: mysql, database

in my database i have many column like this.

```
Vendor     VZWBuildingNumber     VendorSiteID
ADO.NET           0              ACD-MI-12503 
ADO.NET           0              ACD-MI-12518
ADO.NET           0              ACD-MI-12517
```

and i want it like this

```
Vendor     VZWBuildingNumber     VendorSiteID
ADO.NET        012503            ACD-MI-12503 
ADO.NET        012518            ACD-MI-12518
ADO.NET        012517            ACD-MI-12517
```

i want last 5 letter of VendorSiteID and it apper in VZWBuildingNumber where vendor = ADO.NET and VZWBuildingNumber = 0. I tried but not any success Please help me with Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql's [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function is what you are looking for.

> The forms without a len argument return a substring from string str
>   starting at position pos. The forms with a len argument return a
>   substring len characters long from string str, starting at position
>   pos. The forms that use FROM are standard SQL syntax

Thus you can write your query as

```
UPDATE VZWBuildingNumber 
SET VZWBuildingNumber = CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(VendorSiteID, 8, 7))
WHERE Vendor = 'ADO.NET'
```

Comment: it's display...#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM 5)
WHERE Vendor = 'ACD.NET'' at line 1

Comment: i have done like this. UPDATE `vendordata` SET VZWBuildingNumber = concat('0',SUBSTR(VendorSiteID, -5)) WHERE Vendor = 'ADO.NET'

Comment: Yep, that's one way of doing it.